# Android Error Window Causes Back Button to Stop Working

Tags: java, android, overlay, android-windowmanager

I've got an application that should overlay the notification bar and perform actions on touch..

For now, I managed to get it working by creating a system overlay button as:

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            statusBarHeight,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(mView, params);
```

But when I try to click the device back button it doesn't work.

Note that I can't change TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR to TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT as it must overlay the notification bar.

I've also tried adding the flag FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE.. in this case back button works but onTouchEvent not called.

Answer (score 0):

I make this:

```
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                Constant.NOTIFY_HEIGHT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        mParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mNotifyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_safety_count_down_layout, null);
        mNotifyTxt = (TextView) mNotifyView.findViewById(R.id.txt_notification_safety_count_down_time);

        mWindowManager.addView(mNotifyView, mParams);

        mNotifyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SafetyCountDownService.this, DoroAssistanceAppActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.CALL_FROM, Constant.CALL_FROM_NOTIFICATION);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Please try!!!